# How can I stop qterminal from cutting the top half off every line?

Tags: terminal, graphics

I'm running Arch Linux, and using LXQT.  I've just installed qterminal.  At the moment, it looks like this:

[image]

The top half of every line is cut off.  I can fix this by increasing the font size, but I'd rather have the normal font.  I've searched online and gone through all the display settings myself, but I can't work out how to fix this.